# Only allow CloudFormation to delete resources created by CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I want to create permissions for AWS CloudFormation.

I have to provide delete permission. How can I restrict in a way so that it can only delete resources which were created by CloudFormation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS CloudFormation will only delete resources that it originally created.

When deploying a stack, CloudFormation will create resources using the permissions associated with the credentials that created the stack. Or, if an IAM Role is specified when the stack is created, it will use those credentials to create resources.

When deleting resources, it will use the same credentials.

It is not possible to create permissions that say "only delete resources that were created by CloudFormation" because the permissions are defined *outside of* CloudFormation.

I know that CloudFormation adds tags to most (all?) of the resources it creates, so you might be able to do some fancy stuff with tags, but it generally shouldn't be necessary because CloudFormation will only delete resources it originally created.

Comment: Thanks John, in CloudFormation stack we cannot just use deletion?

Comment: @Mandy Sorry, but I do not understand what you are asking when you say "just use deletion". Could you please ask your question with more details?